# Position div horizontally center

Tags: css, css-animations

I want to position a div at the center of the screen. The issue is when the div is small, from left 45% looks fine but when the div is longer(ie more width), I need to make it from left 30%

Is there a smart way to position the div at the center based on the size of div.

```css
body {
background:blue;
}

.box  {
position: absolute;
top:10px;
left:30%;
background:white;
padding:10px;
border-radius:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
This is long div so need left = 30 percent
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can align center the component using `display: flex;` attribute.

[css flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

```css
body {
flex: 1;
background:blue;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}

.box  {
position: absolute;
top:10px;
background:white;
padding:10px;
border-radius:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
This is long div so need left = 30 percent
</div>
```

Comment: +1 Very creative way of doing this. I usually just position in as `left: 50%` and `margin-left: -[[width / 2]]`, but I'll keep this in mind.

Comment: I'm using the div as a widget...So the issue is I can't give body {flex} since it will affect the hosting site. Is there any other fix?

Comment: You can wrapping a widget element by flex element.

Answer (score 1):

You can center it horizontally that way:

```
.box  {
   position: absolute;
   top:10px;
   left:50%;
   background:white;
   padding:10px;
   border-radius:10px;
   transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

to center a div horizontally, a simple solution is to set its margin to "auto":

```css
body {
background:blue;
}

.box  {
width: fit-content;
margin: auto;
background:white;
padding:10px;
border-radius:10px;
}
```